# Projective resolution of a quiver with relations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, quivers

How do we compute the projective resolution of a representation of a quiver with relations.

For example consider the Beilinson quiver $B_4$

[image]$.

with the relations ­$\{\alpha_j^k\alpha_i^{k-1}=\alpha_i^k\alpha_j^{k-1}:1\leq i,j\leq 4,1\leq k\leq 3\}$

Since the Beilinson quiver $B_4$ is derived equivalent to the $\mathfrak{D}^b(\mathbb{P}^3)$, it has finite projective dimension. How do we construct the projective resolution for a representation of this quiver?

I had first posted this question on stackexchage, but received no replies there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, if there are no directed cycles, then the global dimension is finite. It is bounded by the length of the longest directed path.

Comment: Yes, I want to understand how exactly to construct the resolution.

Comment: This boils down to (repeatedly) finding a (minimal) projective cover, which just means finding a minimal generating set.

Comment: If you have a particular representation in mind then you can calculate the projective resolution using the QPA package in GAP. They have command for calculating projective resolution. You can find more information about it here: https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/qpa.html

Comment: Isn’t this Butler and King? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869398975998